# How would I detect the first X and next few characters from every line

Tags: php, regex

I have a log file, it contains 1000 lines of log and I need to detect the first 22 characters and next 15 characters (25th to 40th) of every line. You would have a line like this:

```
    Dec 2, 2014, 11:23 PM - +91 90000 90000: lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum lorem ipsum
```

But it needs to like this

```
     Dec 2, 2014, 11:23 PM
```

and

```
     +91 90000 90000
```

Comment: You added the tags `excel` and `php`. Which language do you need?

Comment: I need it in PHP and Excel both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$handle = fopen("test.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
            echo $datetime= substr($line, 0, 22)."<br>";
            echo $mobile = substr($line, 24, 37)."<br>";
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

**test.txt**

```
Dec 2, 2014, 11:23 PM - +91 90000 90000:
Dec 4, 2015, 11:24 PM - +91 56569 85656:
Dec 25, 2015, 11:24 PM - +91 56569 85656:
```

**Output**

```
Dec 2, 2014, 11:23 PM
+91 90000 90000:
Dec 4, 2015, 11:24 PM
+91 56569 85656:
Dec 25, 2015, 11:24 PM
+91 56569 85656:
```

Comment: Be careful.  `Dec 25, 2015, 11:24 PM - +91 56569 85656:` will not work. Consider using regex instead.

Comment: There will be a whitespace at the end of `$datetime` and at the beginning of `$mobile`. Just count characters. I suggest adding trim()